# constexpr in Node handle

Tags: c++, c++17, nodes, constexpr

I would want to ask for clarification about a specific that the standard indicates for the Node-handle type. I read [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/node_handle) information, where it is specified that Node-handle's default constructor must be declared constexpr, but this specific is not present for any other constructor, destructor or member function.

Could you tell me what is the reason for this choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++17, dynamic memory allocation cannot happen at compile-time. The nodes referenced by a non-empty `node_handle` are the result of dynamic memory allocation. Ergo, they could never work at compile-time, so making them `constexpr` is not possible.

This persists into C++20 because the associative containers are not compatible with `constexpr` allocation support.

Comment: Since C++20 allocators are constexpr, I don't really see why associative containers are not constexpr. The only thing that cannot be done is to "transfer" a compile-time dynamically allocated object to the runtime, but this doesn't prevent the container from being used at compile-time.

Comment: @Alex: The point of node handle extraction is to be able to turn the `const` Key into a non-`const` Key so that you can modify it. There is no legal mechanism in the C++ standard that would allow for this, but standard library implementations are not bound to using legal mechanisms to achieve standard requirements. But compile-time code has to follow the rules.

Comment: Okay I see I hadn't understood that part, thanks!